# Why is this code returns array duplicate?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code

```
$num = 0;
$arr = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $hashed = hash("joaat", "TEST" . $num + $i);
    if (!in_array($hashed, $arr)) {
        array_push($arr, $hashed);
    } else {
        // array_push($arr, $hashed);
        echo "Duplicate " . $hashed . "\n";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "TEST" . $num + $i;
        echo "<br>";
        break;
    }
}

echo "ARRAY---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
echo "<br>";

print_r($arr);
```

As you can see, I create a string such as "Test1", "TEST2", "TEST3"... "TEST10000", and hash it with joaat algorithm. Then I check if the hashed value exist in array $arr. If the value doesn't exist, I add it to the array $arr. If it exist, I print the duplicate hash and the original string and stop the for loop.

The problem is, the program stops because it reaches the *else* condition and shows the duplicate hash and the original string
[image]

But when I search the value in the array, I found no duplicate
[image]

Can anybody explains to me why this happen? Maybe there is flaw in my code?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What does it have anything to do with the question?

Comment: And also, I tried to hash a string twice, and it returns same value

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi a hash, with the same algorythm and the same value will always be the same. That's its main purpose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that your number starts with `0e`. PHP will try to interpret it as a number in scientific notation. Since it starts with `0`, it will always be `0` no matter what's after the `e`.

Try by adding something to the hash, like prepending it with the letter `H`. You won't see the problem anymore.

Now, this happens because strings are converted to numbers behind the hood. **Your real solution is to set the 3rd parameter of in_array to true**. This will switch to strict search.